# how to use image as background in svg of guitar pick shape

Tags: svg, svg-pattern

I want fit image under guitar pick shaped svg element

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" version="1.1" baseProfile="full">
                          <defs>
                              <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">
                                  <image xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/100" width="100" height="100"/>
                              </pattern>
                          </defs>
                          <path d="M8022.333,4996.688a26.281,26.281,0,0,0-9.242-16.959,36.46,36.46,0,0,0-13.247-6.725c-7.448-2.2-15.127-2.789-24.92-2.885-2.04.143-6.126.319-10.184.74a54.277,54.277,0,0,0-15.884,3.963c-7.753,3.325-13.405,8.534-16.07,16.3a33.98,33.98,0,0,0-.728,18.988,81.581,81.581,0,0,0,8.237,20.654,122.339,122.339,0,0,0,22.1,29.732,38.463,38.463,0,0,0,9.7,7.155,10.077,10.077,0,0,0,9.76-.12,40.637,40.637,0,0,0,4.96-3.138,68.929,68.929,0,0,0,11.474-11.293,122.777,122.777,0,0,0,21.05-35.139C8021.942,5011.088,8023.451,5004.055,8022.333,4996.688Zm-69.877,13.931a4.186,4.186,0,0,0,.876,1.31,4.018,4.018,0,0,0,1.285.865,3.927,3.927,0,0,0,1.556.312,4.04,4.04,0,0,0,3.058-1.394l.3-.32,3.159,1.832-.416.508a7.635,7.635,0,0,1-6.1,3.056,7.428,7.428,0,0,1-2.956-.6,7.814,7.814,0,0,1-2.457-1.672,7.815,7.815,0,0,1,0-10.94,7.805,7.805,0,0,1,2.458-1.672,7.419,7.419,0,0,1,2.955-.6,7.637,7.637,0,0,1,6.1,3.055l.416.508-3.159,1.832-.3-.32a4.044,4.044,0,0,0-3.058-1.394,3.933,3.933,0,0,0-1.556.313,4.027,4.027,0,0,0-1.284.864,4.191,4.191,0,0,0-.877,1.31,4,4,0,0,0,0,3.15Zm24.893,6.026h-3.605v-9.312a2.55,2.55,0,0,0-.774-1.886,2.714,2.714,0,0,0-.836-.568,2.338,2.338,0,0,0-.955-.21,2.462,2.462,0,0,0-1.82.778,2.555,2.555,0,0,0-.773,1.886v9.312h-3.6V4996.51h3.6v5.195a4.915,4.915,0,0,1,2.594-.718,5.935,5.935,0,0,1,2.375.488,6.358,6.358,0,0,1,1.988,1.358l.007.007a6.529,6.529,0,0,1,1.319,2.042,6.42,6.42,0,0,1,.481,2.451Zm9.51-11.571a2.441,2.441,0,0,0-.989-.263,1.891,1.891,0,0,0-1.465.62,2.25,2.25,0,0,0-.645,1.588v9.625h-3.549v-9.625a5.937,5.937,0,0,1,3.22-5.313l.02-.01a5.592,5.592,0,0,1,2.42-.539,5.316,5.316,0,0,1,1.993.382,7.532,7.532,0,0,1,1.933,1.2l.615.506-3.288,1.951Zm18.373,11.571h-3.606v-1.42a7.281,7.281,0,0,1-1.337.875,6.158,6.158,0,0,1-2.817.688,7.68,7.68,0,0,1-3.026-.6,7.26,7.26,0,0,1-2.456-1.713,8.1,8.1,0,0,1-1.654-2.52,7.962,7.962,0,0,1,0-6.048,8.086,8.086,0,0,1,1.66-2.526,7.233,7.233,0,0,1,2.451-1.708,7.667,7.667,0,0,1,3.024-.6,6.521,6.521,0,0,1,2.926.657,6.42,6.42,0,0,1,1.228.792V4996.6h3.606Z" transform="translate(-7931.052 -4970.12)" fill="url(#img1)"/>                            
                      </svg>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Isn't tht what you've already done?

Comment: You want to adjust `<svg>` width and height to those of the image?